# How can convert log file time in this format "23-May-17 12:05:37" in log4js package using node js

Tags: node.js, date, configuration, log4js-node

I am trying to change log time this date time format [2017-05-23 12:05:37.327] into this  23-May-17 12:05:37.
I am using this package:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/log4js

Here is file configuration of node4js.

```
     {
       "appenders": [
      {

        "type": "file",
       "filename": "logs/v_1_0_9.log",
       "maxLogSize":1073741824,
       "backups": 10,
       "pattern": "%d{dd/MM hh:mm} %-5p %m"

        "category": "logger"
        }
      ],
            "replaceConsole": true
      }
```

**Output of my code**

[2017-05-24 15:57:00.924] [INFO] logger - tetsting

but above output is not my expected.

**Expected output here**:

[23-May-17 12:05:37] [INFO] logger - tetsting

Please help Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sloution:

```
const date = new Date('2017-05-23 12:05:37.327').toString('dd-MMM-yy hh:mm:ss')
```

EDIT: Sorry, here is a log4js solution:

```
var log4js = require('log4js');
var monthNames = [
  "January", "February", "March",
  "April", "May", "June", "July",
  "August", "September", "October",
  "November", "December"
];

log4js.configure({
  appenders: [{
    type: "console",
    layout: {
      type: "pattern",
      pattern: "%x{ln} %-5p %m",
      tokens: {
        ln: function (data) {
          const date = new Date();
          var day = date.getDate();
          var monthIndex = date.getMonth();
          var year = date.getFullYear();
          var hours = date.getHours();
          var minutes = date.getMinutes();
          var seconds = date.getSeconds();
          return day + '-' + monthNames[monthIndex] + '-' + year + ' ' + hours + ':' + minutes + ':'
            + seconds;
        }
      }
    }
  }],
});

var logger = log4js.getLogger('cheese');
logger.debug('test');
```

Output: `29-May-2017 14:39:4 DEBUG test`

EDIT 2:
conf.json:

```
{
  "appenders": [
    {
      "type": "console",
      "layout": {
        "type": "pattern",
        "pattern": "%x{ln} %-5p %m",
        "tokens": {}
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

logger.js:

```
var log4js = require('log4js');
var config = require('./conf.json')
var monthNames = [
  "January", "February", "March",
  "April", "May", "June", "July",
  "August", "September", "October",
  "November", "December"
];
config.appenders[0].layout.tokens.ln = function () {
  const date = new Date();
  var day = date.getDate();
  var monthIndex = date.getMonth();
  var year = date.getFullYear();
  var hours = date.getHours();
  var minutes = date.getMinutes();
  var seconds = date.getSeconds();
  return day + '-' + monthNames[monthIndex] + '-' + year + ' ' + hours + ':' + minutes + ':'
    + seconds;
};
log4js.configure(config);

var logger = log4js.getLogger('cheese');
logger.debug('test');
```

Comment: But i want to define in json file pattern. 
"pattern": "%d{dd/MM hh:mm} %-5p %m"

this logger function logger.info("tetsting");

Comment: Did you understand the question? @Dominik Dragičević

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to inclode log4j configuration. I edited my post and it should be ok now. @RaheelAslam

Comment: when i write this configuration  code into our  log4js.json file it's displaying error and json file we can't define variable.How does we can set these configuration.
Because i have made the separate configuration file of json and including this file in other file

Comment: You should put it in .js file, not .json

Comment: But i want to put in json file. not for js file

Comment: well, you can't put javascript function into json file. 
You have 2 options:

1.) Define config file in .json, but leave `token` property as an empty object. When you require that file in .js file, set token function as a valueo of `token` property.

2.) use .js for config file and export it with `module.exports`

Comment: @ Dominik Dragičević  
can you send me the complete format for this.?